# Python - If statement to check against a range of choices an

Tags: python, if-statement

I iterate across a list of files and want to check if they have one of many extensions before processing. Is it possible to accomplish this avoiding both these scenarios ?
- Checking for each extension through an OR statement (i.e. hard-coding)
- A loop within a loop

Construct so far:

```
#Iterate over files
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+dataDir):
    #iterate over ext (want to avoid)
    for u in ['jpg','txt'] :
        if filename.endswith(u):
            print("An ext of my choice found!")
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Thanks in advance.
regards,
Sundaresh

Comment: Have you thought about using a Dictionary? This would be a great use for a case/switch statement, which Python has no need for. I would try it with a dictionary.

Comment: @Sufiyan Ghori - thank you for alerting me to the duplicate - the any() answers my question and provides a nifty manner.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are doing is fine. The only change I would suggest is stylistic, to make sure the purpose of your for loop is not multiple indentations deep. Also, the `else` part is not necessary in this particular case.

```
#Iterate over files
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+dataDir):
    #iterate over ext (want to avoid)
    for u not in ['jpg','txt']:
        continue
    if not filename.endswith(u):
        continue
    print("An ext of my choice found!")
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel the any() function (in another note) answers my question, but your suggestion on keeping the number of indentations to a minimum is appreciated.